# Fancybox autoload only once

Tags: cookies, popup, fancybox

I am AutoLoading a Fancybox popup in my homepage but it opens every time a user visits the page. I would like to make the popup open only the first time a user visits homepage and then never after that.

I read I could use the jQuery cookie plugin to write a cookie when user lands to the homepage, after the first popup open. This would be wired to the cookie in order to not open it again if the cookie exists? Is this approach correct?

My popup looks like this:

```
$("a#popup").fancybox({
        'overlayOpacity':   0.5, 
        'overlayColor': '#0a1539',                      
    }).trigger('click');
```

What should I add to use the jQuery cookie plugin, write one cookie and wire it to the popup?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Follow the steps below:

1. Check if cookie exists.
2. If it does not exist, create a cookie and give it some value.
3. In the same block fire your fancybox code.

This will prevent you from firing the fancybox each time.

Note: Let me know if you need the code. It is pretty simple though.

**Edit:**

1. [Download](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt) the jQuery cookie plugin.
2. Use following code:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var check_cookie = $.cookie('the_cookie');
      if(check_cookie == null){
       $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
       //fire your fancybox here
      }
   });
   ```

Comment: Yes I need it if you can, I'm pretty new with cookies.                           But..I need the jquery cookie plugin or not to do what you suggest ? thanks a lot

Comment: No problem. Mark it as answered if you got what you want.